¿como agrego un nuevo componente en vue.js?
Estoy trabajando con una app web (utilizando vue.js, como framework), el problema es que quiero agregar una nueva opcion a un menú que contiene la app en la que estoy trabajando, hasta el momento en la parte del código donde estan plasmadas las otras opciones, ya he agreagado el codigo para representar la nueva opcion en el menú, esta nueva opción tiene el nombre de "Legal" y al desplegarse esta nueva opción debe mostrar una subopcion con el nombre de "Tablero de Revisión de Solicitudes" y despues emepezar a trabajar sobre ese tablero.
he probado de agregar un nuevo componente, pero no logro obtener la vista de la nueva opción en el menú de la app, lo que espero es que se logre ver la vista de la nueva opcion "Legal" y"Tablero de Revisión de Solicitudes"

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! perfecto.. eso es lo que queres.. pero no podemos ayudarte a menos que sepamos que problemas tuviste con eso...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
